# Wrong arguments at ruby API in c-level

Tags: c, ruby

I created ruby method in C using Ruby API which receive 3 string arguments:

```
VALUE cache_class = rb_define_class_under(class, CACHE_CLASS_NAME, rb_cObject);

rb_define_method(cache_class, "cache_test_result", cache_test_result, 3);
```

In **test.rb** I called method:

```
Cache.new.cache_test_result("str1", "str2", "str3")
```

And C **cache_test_result** function works strange:

```c
VALUE cache_test_result(VALUE str1, VALUE str2, VALUE str3) {
   int rstr1_len = RSTRING_LEN(str1) + 1;
   char buf_str1[rstr1_len];
   strlcpy(buf_str1, RSTRING_PTR(str1), rstr1_len);

   int rstr2_len = RSTRING_LEN(str2) + 1;
   char buf_str2[rstr2_len];
   strlcpy(buf_str2, RSTRING_PTR(str2), rstr2_len);

   int rstr3_len = RSTRING_LEN(str3) + 1;
   char buf_str3[rstr3_len];
   strlcpy(buf_str3, RSTRING_PTR(str3), rstr3_len);

   printf("buf_str1: %s\n", buf_str1);
   printf("buf_str2: %s\n", buf_str2);
   printf("buf_str3: %s\n", buf_str3);
}
```

**output** of this function:

```
buf_str1: 
buf_str2: str1
buf_str3: str2
```

why args has offset...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[To quote the documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/doc/extension_rdoc.html#label-Write+the+C+Code):

> The first argument of the C function is the self, the rest are the arguments to the method.

Which means you need to adjust the function prototype and add an additional parameter, e.g.:

```
VALUE cache_test_result(VALUE self, VALUE str1, VALUE str2, VALUE str3) {
```

And since a C object of type `VALUE` can be everything (a Ruby string, integer or nil) never use `RSTRING_{PTR,LEN}` and similar (macro) functions without being sure of its Ruby type. Instead you may use [`Check_Type`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/doc/extension_rdoc.html#label-Check+Data+Type+of+the+VALUE), [`StringValuePtr`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/doc/extension_rdoc.html#label-Convert+VALUE+into+C+Data), or [`StringValueCStr`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/doc/extension_rdoc.html#label-Convert+VALUE+into+C+Data) depending on the use case.

Your example could be rewritten as:

```
VALUE cache_test_result(VALUE self, VALUE str1, VALUE str2, VALUE str3) {
   // Check if each value is a Ruby string
   // (or can be implicitly converted to one) and
   // return a pointer to its underlying C string.
   // It it also checked if the Ruby string contains NUL.
   // If any check fails an exception is raised.
   const char *buf_str1 = StringValueCStr(str1);
   const char *buf_str2 = StringValueCStr(str2);
   const char *buf_str3 = StringValueCStr(str3);
   // print each underlying C string
   printf("buf_str1: %s\n", buf_str1);
   printf("buf_str2: %s\n", buf_str2);
   printf("buf_str3: %s\n", buf_str3);
}
```